# How to handle keyboard mic button event on iPhone

Tags: ios, uitextfield, uisearchbar, uikeyboard

I have this UISearchBar sits on top of self.view. With the default keyboard shown when it became first responder, I wonder if there's any way to pick up a touch event of the microphone button. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: I doubt it, since the keyboard is running in a different UNIX process and there's a sandbox between it and your app. The button might not even exist, depending what keyboard the user has active.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are viewing this microphone icon because your iPhone dictation is switched on under Settings>General>Keyboard>Dictation or Settings-->General-->Siri.

I think you can use text input mode to identify which input mode is currently going on.

```
UITextInputCurrentInputModeDidChangeNotification
```

Reference - https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextinputmode?language=objc